# How to change dynamically height of UITableViewCell using heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have prototype cell. I have several labels inside. I use auto-layout to resize one of the labels to change height and to fit content. I need to resize the whole `UITableViewCell`.

On the event `heightForRowAtIndexPath` I create an dummy cell to calculate height. I use following [example](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html). I have to set proper **height**. My problem is that it returns 0.

The problem in my point of view is in the following code:

```
CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView
               systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
return size.height+1;
```

The content view has height of 44, but the method returns 0. As a result I see the cell bu the height is 1.

**EDIT:**

My code for whole method is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self configureCell:self.prototypeCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.prototypeCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.twDetails.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.prototypeCell.bounds));

    //[self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.prototypeCell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.prototypeCell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    return size.height+1;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I think I am wrong calling configureCell again in this place:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PESvcPaymentDetailsCell *dispositionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:dispositionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.row <= singApp.operationPostpaidDispositionsList.dispositionsCount - 1) {

       [self configureCell:dispositionCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
    else {
    }

    //[tvCellsArray addObject:dispositionCell];
    return dispositionCell;
}
```

So may be I initialise it again, by doing this?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes, @l0gg3r. I use auto-layout. I tried to use it to make resize, but in that case the label with extra data was not stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to reconfigure your custom cell temporarily for the indexPath and return its height.

In your configureCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method- make sure you're adding any views/labels to the cell's contentView.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Instantiate a mock custom cell
    PESvcPaymentDetailsCell *dispositionCell = [[PESvcPaymentDetailsCell alloc] init];

    // Configure it based on the index path
    [self configureCell:dispositionCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Make sure its frame is updated
    [dispositionCell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [dispositionCell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

    // Return the height
    return [dispositionCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, @Matt Tang but it is still return 0. I have only layoutIfNeeded, but only on `prototype cell` itself.

Comment: Do you really need to set the prototypeCell's actual bound? It may interfere with the contentView's frame. Could you comment out where you set self.prototypeCell.bounds ?

Comment: Only here, @Matt Tang, I set this `bounds`. I use ready example (as mentioned in my question). I thought that when I create `prototype` and fill it with my data I will have proper bounds. And using that command I will take them and extract from it proper height. After that I execute once again `configureCell` in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (where I get my real cell).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Add some logging to the code to see what's actually going on. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry @Matt Tang, but I think I make a general mistake. Here is the LOG: 2014-11-13 10:22:18.697 PA-PAY[12283:607] cell frame after configureCell: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-11-13 10:22:22.294 PA-PAY[12283:607] cell frame after bounds change: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-11-13 10:22:27.864 PA-PAY[12283:607] cell frame after layout update: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-11-13 10:22:29.978 PA-PAY[12283:607] cell frame after systemLayout call: {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}. First the height 44 is not correct, because I read that 44 is set as default. Second I have bottom border of my cell which is at the top of the TV

Comment: ... and I can not select Cell which means that height is 0 (I already mentioned footer of the cell visible at the top of Table View)

Comment: @new2ios I updated my answer. Try to add some logging to check that the contentView height is updating.